# Как использовать пространства имён в unity и какие для чего нужны?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда я создаю скрипты там подключаются разные библиотеки, такие как UnityEngine, SystemCollection и т.д. Какие библиотеки существуют в юнити и за что они отвечают?

Comment: ты хочешь ответ про все библиотеки или ссылку на документацию?..

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/  - слева меню. кликай сколько угодно пока самоизоляция не закончится)))